# Check folder if exists or not in Documents Folder

Tags: c#, uwp, directory

I have a folder named "kipin" which contains several files in the Documents folder. I want to check if the "kipin" folder is in the Documents folder
Code:

```
string kipindoc = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);

if (Directory.Exists(@kipindoc + @"\kipin"))
{
    //code
}
else
{
    loading.IsActive = false;
    MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog("Buku Pengetahuan Umum tidak tersedia");
    messageDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("Kembali", (command) =>
    {
        this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
    }));
    await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

I have a problem, that is always displaying message dialog (return false), whereas folder "kipin" contained in Documents folder. How to handle it?

Comment: You could start by telling us what the error message is. It's worth noting that in your check, you don't once reference `kipin`. The directory you check exists, for my user, would be `c:\users\john\documents\files`.

Comment: @john I believe what they mean is that they always see the message they display in the `else` branch, i.e. their `Directory.Exists` returns false.

Comment: "an error message"    it sure would be easier if we knew what that said.

Comment: You might be right, although the question would be better if that was clarified.

Comment: There was no error message, but it was immediately thrown into the else so the message dialog appeared as in my code ("Buku Pengetahuan Umum tidak tersedia")

Comment: @Rose please check in which user context visual studio is running. Or check if the files folder is in the right documents folder for that user.You can set a breakpoint and check the variable kipindoc and copy the value to explorer and check for the right folder.

Comment: This problem is only when checking it, but to display files in the documents folder does not occur a problem. I tried comment if and else, the file can be displayed and no problem occurs. But if I add if and else, then always return false

Comment: @Rose can you show what is inside the if?

Comment: @MStoerzel I've added it in my post

Comment: @MStoerzel I have added the code in the id, but you suggest to delete it

Comment: @Rose Check if you are really dealing with the right folder with the line `Process.Start(kipindoc)` right before if. There you should see if the folder is correct

Comment: By default, an UWP app is not allowed to access the Documents folder. Follow the steps listed in the Documents section here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/apps/hh464936(v=win.10)#special-capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (Directory.Exists(@kipindoc + @"\files"))
```

to

```
if (Directory.Exists(@kipindoc + @"\kipin"))
```

At the moment, you're checking for a folder named 'files', not a folder called 'kipin'

---

Ok. Add the following line of code above `if (Directory.Exists(@kipindoc + @"\kipin"))`

```
Console.Write(@kipindoc + @"\kipin");
```

This will output the directory path that you are checking to the output window in Visual Studio. Does the path look correct? Is it the same path you see in windows Explorer when you navigate to your kipin folder?

Comment: I'm sorry to write it wrong. I use if (Directory.Exists(@kipindoc + @"\kipin")), but still return false

Comment: See my update!!

Comment: path: C:\\Users\\cielo\\Documents\\kipin

Comment: @Rose Try to understand that even if the path is valid, `Directory.Exists` will return false because your application is not allowed to access that directory.